# Adding an image to a CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, core-animation, cashapelayer

I'm attempting to render a static image inside a `CAShapeLayer` that is nested within a `UIView`'s layer. All of the adornments of the shape (i.e. borders, colors, paths, etc.) render properly in the view.

*However*, the supplied `CGImage` for the `CALayer.contents` property does not render in the view at any point (as far as I can tell). I've been trying to figure this behavior out for a while and am stumped with the documentation from Apple:

> If you are using the layer to display a **static image**, you can **set this property to the CGImage containing the image** you want to display.... Assigning a value to this property causes the layer to use your image rather than create a separate backing store.
>
> If the layer object is tied to a view object, you should **avoid setting the contents of this property directly**. The interplay between views and layers **usually results in the view replacing the contents of this property during a subsequent update**.

That's great to know! It's probably exactly what's happening in this scenario: the UIView is updating and replacing its contents. Except the provided workaround isn't very clear and I haven't been able to find examples that solve this problem.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to set a static image *'indirectly'* on a CAShapeLayer and avoid having it removed by the superview (almost immediately)?

Comment: as far as I know. Each view has a calayer. Then you can add your shape layer to this layer.  Self.view.layer.addsublayer(myshapelayer) from your viewcontroller. Then you don’t need to worry about the content issue. Please show your example code next time. So we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought you couldn't install an image into the contents of a CAShapeLayer and have it work, but I was wrong. It does work. Consider this code:

```
class ImageWithShapeView: UIView {

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        shapeLayer.frame = self.bounds
        //Load an image into the shape layer's contents property.
        if let image = UIImage(named: "WareToLogo") {
            shapeLayer.contents = image.cgImage
            layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        }
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        let radius = (bounds.midX + bounds.midY) / 4.0
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY), radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2, clockwise: true)
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height))
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.height))
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    }
}
```

That works, and creates the following when I add an `ImageWithShapeView` to my project. (I'm using a storyboard, so I implemented `UIView.init(coder:)`. If you're creating your views in code you'll probably want to implement `UIView.init(frame:)` instead)

[image]